# Python 3 Modules Do Not Work

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opengl, python-imaging-library

I recently tried to install Pillow, for Python 3.5. From the command line, `from PIL import Image` works, but that does not work for IDLE. When I installed Pillow, it said that it was installed to `C:\Users\arkj7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages`
When I try to import Image from Pillow, it says,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Users\arkj7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 67, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'
```

but when I run `import PIL` it seems to work. I am running Windows 10.

Edit: No other modules work, they give similar error messages.

2nd Edit: This just keeps getting weirder, when I try to import PyEnchant, it works from the command line, but not IDLE. It gives me the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import enchant
  File "C:\Users\arkj7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\enchant\__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    from enchant import _enchant as _e
  File "C:\Users\arkj7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\enchant\_enchant.py", line 102, in <module>
    raise WinError()
OSError: [WinError 193] <no description>
```

However, modules like [translate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/translate/), work just fine.

Edit 3:

All modules except PIL, PyEnchant, and OpenCV work. OpenCV works from the command line, where I am running Python 3.5.2, but not from IDLE, where I am also running Python 3.5.2. I got OpenCV from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv), and I used `opencv_python-3.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl`. I installed it using `pip install opencv_python-3.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl`, and I get this error message from IDLE:

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Edit 4:
I installed PyOpenGL like this, `pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate`. From the command prompt, some things work, and others don't, this is what I get:

```
>>> import OpenGL
>>> from OpenGLContext import testingcontext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'OpenGLContext'
>>> from OpenGL.GL import *
```

This is what I get from IDLE:

```
>>> import OpenGL
>>> from OpenGLContext import testingcontext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from OpenGLContext import testingcontext
ImportError: No module named 'OpenGLContext'
>>> import OpenGLContext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import OpenGLContext
ImportError: No module named 'OpenGLContext'
>>> from OpenGL.GL import *
OpenGL_accelerate seems to be installed, but unable to import error checking entry point!
Unable to load ArrayDatatype accelerator from OpenGL_accelerate
Unable to load converters accelerators (wrapper, arraydatatype) from OpenGL_accelerate
Unable to load arrayhelpers accelerator from OpenGL_accelerate
OpenGL_accelerate seems to be installed, but unable to import expected wrapper entry points!
Unable to load VBO accelerator from OpenGL_accelerate
```

Comment: Please show the complete error message, not just the last line.

Comment: How did you install? Can you prove that you are running the same version of python from idle as from the command line? Do you get this error even when the idle document is reduced to a single import line? Can you import any other of the PIL modules?

Comment: @JamesK I was using the shell, but it does not work in a file either.

Comment: "No other modules work,". What other modules? Other PIL modules, or other packages?

Comment: For Pillow, it appears the shared object (binary) is missing (since `import PIL` works). Can you see any `_imaging*.so` files in `C:\Users\arkj7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PIL\`?

Comment: @Evert Even other packages do not work. Under the PIL folder, there are lots of _imaging*.pyd, but not _imaging*.so.

Comment: Turns out I made a mistake with a different modules, PIL is the only module that does not work.